# Error While Producing Message : Broker: Message size too large

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

we deployed 3 replicas kafka cluster with Strimzi Operator to our kubernetes cluster, so far everything was fine. We configured our broker to fetch big messages, but unfortunately we faced with the Error at tittle "Error While Producing Message : Broker: Message size too large".
Strimzi Kafka Operator (https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/)
This is our kafka object config, also I recreated topics after enable this conf.

```
kafka:
config:
default.replication.factor: 3
fetch.max.bytes: "15728641"
inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.3"
max.message.bytes: "15728640"
max.partition.fetch.bytes: "15728640"
max.request.size: "15728640"
message.max.bytes: "15728640"
min.insync.replicas: 2
offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
replica.fetch.max.bytes: "15728640"
socket.request.max.bytes: "15728640"
transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
```

what am I missing here ?
Thanks for your help.

I try to send larger than 8MB messages to kafka brokers and I expecting that brokers need to accept this messages.

Comment: The producer needs configured as well